# SVN merge just overwrites all files

Tags: svn, version-control

When i try to merge from branch to trunk using SVNTortoise, it just overwrites everything with branch copy, doesn't ask me to resolve any conflicts. Does anybody know why? "Merge non-interactive" checkbox is not checked.

Comment: do you use "reintegrate" merge mode?

Comment: Yes, i use "reintegrate" mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Reintegrate branch" algorithm differs from a regular merge. It assumes that you already merged everything from trunk to feature branch and thus resolved conflicts there. So reintegrating merge (almost) copies feature branch to the trunk.

Citation from http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html

> All changes to trunk made during branch development must have been merged across to the branch (or marked as having been merged).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you may have changes in your working copy, and it's those changes you're expecting to be merged. But if you merge from branch to trunk and store the results in your working copy, then working-copy changes aren't even considered; they are simply overwritten. Either commit your changes to the trunk before the merge, *or* store the result of the merge directly to trunk, not to your working copy.

Comment: All changes were commited to the trunk before merging.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the action of the revision of the branch you try to merge from is "Added". This is why the merge just overwrites all files. 
[image]

This is revision graph where SVN merge overwrites all files:
[image]

You should change the action of the revision from "Added" to "Modified" by committing something new to your branch.

Updating the branch by adding a space.
[image]

[image]

Revision graph after updating the branch

[image]

Now when you merge from your branch, you should see the conflict; and SVN would ask you to resolve it manually.

[image]